# Sharepoint 2010 - Caching data

Tags: caching, sharepoint-2010

I am developing a intranet sharepoint 2010 and to optimize the performance I would place much of data that is used for example to fill comboboxs and ListViews in the cache. What is the best approach to implement this feature? My idea was to use the ASP.NET cache.

Note: Much of the data are returned directly by web services and others are external sharepoint lists. The site will be installed in a web farm.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the ASP.NET cache. Then you do not have to create your own and implement thingies such as thread support, dependencies etc.

Answer (score 0):

Like most of the SP farms out there, if you have multiple web front ends (WFE's) in your farm then simple asp.net caching methodology is not going to be enough and might not work at all in some cases.

You need a product like NCache/Appfabric. It gets complex if your sharepoint environment has multiple farms distributed across the world.